# Link pages between wordpress multisites

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have two websites in different languages on one wordpress (multisite).

Pages from a site to another have different IDs, names (because of language), etc... And woocommerce is installed on both websites (meaning there are products).

I'm looking for a way to connect pages from site 1 to site 2 (and reverse) to show a link that would let users go from their language to another but arriving on the "same" page.

I know this is not the best way to have a multilingual website on wordpress but it has been installed that way and we are trying to figure out a way to connect these pages. Maybe that would be useful to someone else for another reason, that's why I'm asking it.

My first idea would be to add an input on the post (pages, articles, product) and fill it with the link of the "sibling". This is time consuming at first (to do this for all the content that is already online) but could work. Best way would be to have a select menu of all the other site pages to select the specific page/article/product but I don't really know how to do this.

And maybe.. maybe there is already a plugin that does that kind of thing, if yes, that would be great.

Thanks !